# drag and drop with Angular 7 Material CDK

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7, angular-cdk

I have a requirement to implement drag and drop in angular 7. 
I will have multiple containers for dropping. The issue I am facing is, if I drag an item over a drop container, and drop to the container below, it gets dropped in the first container itself.

[stackblitz link:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68mqyx?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html)

In the above example, I want to move an item from **To Do** to **Done list 2** .
However, If I drag the item over Done list1 and drop in Done List2, it gets dropped to Done list1 itself.

Comment: That is very unusual. It looks like you can drag it from To Do to Done list 2, but you cannot touch the Done List 1 mid ways. and this also applies for To Do -> Done list 2 -> done list 1.

Comment: It is very likely because: When it touches the Done list 1, it will become member of it, and then (as you have defined) you cannot transfer from done list 1 to done list 2.

Comment: I was missing this point             "If you have an unknown number of connected drop lists, you can use the cdkDropListGroup directive to set up the connection automatically. Note that any new cdkDropList that is added under a group will be connected to all other automatically."  doc: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#attaching-data

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing cdkDropListConnectedTo attribute value.

demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68mqyx-g6s8r4?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html